# Having trouble with mold in one spot

Tags: bathroom, mold

This is between a toilet and a bathtub. For whatever reason moisture is condensing here everyday. It is dry after a shower but at some point overnight it starts condensing. My main question is what is the best way to repair this spot? Will I need to remove the drywall or should I attempt to sand this area down and repaint?

[image: moldy wall between toilet & tub]

Answer (score 1):

Sanding and repainting will only fix it cosmetically. You might have a bigger issue with a leak in the wall or condensation from the toilet. OR water overspray from your showering.

If you use a shower curtain, you can address the spraying by installing pre-made plastic corners on the top outer edge of your tub. If that is the only issue, after that you can do a cosmetic fix....(is the wall plaster so you mention sanding?)

Otherwise you can investigate the toilet for condensation. You can thereafter purchase or rent an inspection camera, drill a 3/4 -inch hole in the wall and look in the wall to find any interior pipe leaks. You may have to cut the wall open. If there is an access panel on the opposite side of this wall, then open it and look around. Good luck and let us know what you find.

Comment: So I installed a plastic guard and redid the caulking at this spot of the bathtub. However I noticed that still I was getting this condensation. I looked under the house at this spot and while it is damp on the ground the wood and pipes are dry and aren't leaking. This wall is an exterior wall so I can't easily open it up and look in with a camera with the insulation there. I think I'm just getting condensation from the air so I will install a dehumidifier and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: You may have a roof or gutter leak. I would still use the inspection camera to peek inside the wall. Is there a bathroom fan? Is it working properly and is it used everytime someone takes a shower?

Comment: Yep there is a bathroom fan and it works well. It's just a very small bathroom (shower and toilet only). So far it hasn't been a problem at all with the dehumidifier, but I will try to get ahold of a camera and look in the wall. Rain is rare here and the problem happened everyday so I don't suspect a leak from the roof. And it's a vaulted ceiling so no pipes in the roof.